# Gitignore cloud9 files

Tags: git, gitignore, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to figure out how to make my .gitignore file ignore the .c9 files generated the Cloud9 IDE. Also once I push with the gitignore changes will it automatically remove the .c9 files I have previously there? Or would I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a line with `.c9/` to include contents of `.c9` folder or add a line with `.*` to ignore all hidden files starting with `.`.
Modifying `.gitignore` doesn't change files added to git, you need to remove them separately.